# Turning off representation descriptions in ArcMap table of contents?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, table-of-contents, representation

Using ArcMap 10.3.1, advanced, how do I turn off the display of the layer representation descriptions in the TOC?  I've highlighted what I'm trying to turn off in the screenshot below.

Nothing in the Arc help mentions this, nor have I found anything in the Layer Properties window (also shown in the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Can you click on the description in the TOC, hit F2 to rename, and delete the text?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Highlighting the description and hitting F2 does not allow the text to be renamed or deleted.  I also tried r-clicking the text, but nothing happened...

Comment: Because that is not a symbology you can't remove it. There is same comportment with geostatistical reprentation layer. You can edit the group of symbol in toc or symbology for simple representation

Comment: There is a video of [all possibilities](http://www.esri.com/videos/watch?videoid=2998&isLegacy=true&title=working-with-cartographic-representations). It speak about rename rules but if representation don't have name (and I don't think it's possible.), it still remains **Representation:**

Comment: Is this for showing in legend?

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't seem to be removable as a representation.  You could:

- Recreate the symbology using e.g. categories.  You would then be able to 'F2' rename it as blank.
- If it is just for the legend being drawn in layout view then you can right click the legend and convert to graphics.  Un-group as necessary and then delete that line.  Only do this at the very end else if you make a change to it then you will have to redo that process.